# Condition to add a product to cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart

I have to product : ProductA and ProductB.

I want to hide ProductB from the catalog and show it only on the ProductA page.

But, the user can't add to cart the ProductB if the ProductA is not added in the cart.

How do I do this things ?

Comment: you need to used magento event observer.

Comment: That's what I thought. I've read that : https://webkul.com/blog/restrict-add-cart-according-condition-magneto2/ but I  don't know if it's what I'm looking for

Comment: yes, that can help you to fullfill your requirement.

Comment: How do I get current product with my observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with event observer, `use catalog_product_collection_load_after` event, and you can get all of products at the page with this code :

```
$collections = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
```

And if you want to get each product (get the SKU for example), you can do it like this :

```
foreach( $collections as $collection ) {
    $allSKU[] = $collection->getSku()
}
```

You can check another things like how to create a event observer [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) or [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html) for more simple thing.

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9, how can i restrict some of the products like this kind of products you should purchase alone. so how can i use the add-to-cart function, if click my restricted products, show to the customer like you need to purchase this product alone, how can i add this? @Edwin Widhiyanto

Comment: you should override the magento module to give more condition, and to show the message you could use observer and check before the item placed in your cart. you should create your own question thread anyway